# How to detect an active child menu from a parent menu?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu

Creating a single level menu can easily be achieved with a single state holding the active menu:

```js
import React from 'react';

import { Menu } from './Menu';

export const App = () => {
  const [active, setActive] = React.useState<React.ReactNode>(null);
  return (
    <>
      <Menu label="A" active={active} setActive={setActive}>
        <Menu label="A.A" active={active} setActive={setActive} />
        <Menu label="A.B" active={active} setActive={setActive} />
      </Menu>
      <Menu label="B" active={active} setActive={setActive}>
        <Menu label="B.A" active={active} setActive={setActive} />
        <Menu label="B.B" active={active} setActive={setActive} />
      </Menu>
    </>
  );
};
```

```js
import React from 'react';

type Props = {
  label: string;
  active?: HTMLElement;
  setActive?: (active: HTMLElement) => void;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
};

export const Menu = ({ label, active, setActive, children }: Props) => {
  const ref = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const onClick = () => setActive?.(children && ref.current);
  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      <button type="button" onClick={onClick}>
        {label}
      </button>
      {active && active === ref.current && children}
    </div>
  );
};
```

But creating a multiple level menu is difficult because when a child menu is active its parents also need to be active and I don’t know how to implement that:

```js
import React from 'react';

import { Menu } from './Menu';

export const App = () => {
  const [active, setActive] = React.useState<React.ReactNode>(null);
  return (
    <>
      <Menu label="A" active={active} setActive={setActive}>
        <Menu label="A.A" active={active} setActive={setActive}>
          <Menu label="A.A.A" active={active} setActive={setActive} />
          <Menu label="A.A.B" active={active} setActive={setActive} />
        </Menu>
        <Menu label="A.B" active={active} setActive={setActive}>
          <Menu label="A.B.A" active={active} setActive={setActive} />
          <Menu label="A.B.B" active={active} setActive={setActive} />
        </Menu>
      </Menu>
      <Menu label="B" active={active} setActive={setActive}>
        <Menu label="B.A" active={active} setActive={setActive}>
          <Menu label="B.A.A" active={active} setActive={setActive} />
          <Menu label="B.A.B" active={active} setActive={setActive} />
        </Menu>
        <Menu label="B.B" active={active} setActive={setActive}>
          <Menu label="B.B.A" active={active} setActive={setActive} />
          <Menu label="B.B.B" active={active} setActive={setActive} />
        </Menu>
      </Menu>
    </>
  );
};
```

```js
import React from 'react';

type Props = {
  label: string;
  active?: HTMLElement;
  setActive?: (active: HTMLElement) => void;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
};

export const Menu = ({ label, active, setActive, children }: Props) => {
  const ref = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const onClick = () => setActive?.(children && ref.current);
  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      <button type="button" onClick={onClick}>
        {label}
      </button>
      {active && Array.isArray(children) && children.includes(active) && children}  // DOES NOT WORK!
    </div>
  );
};
```

`children.includes(active)` is always `false` because children is a `React.ReactNode` whereas `active` is an `HTMLElement`. How to cast the types to make the comparison work?

Answer (score 0):

It is too complex to find if ReactNode is active or not (and reason for that many different props ReactNode has), and i would edit menu so it could be more flexible

```
<Menu menus={ [{label: "A", key: "1", menus: [{label: "A.A" }]}, ... and so on ] }
```

and inside Menu

```
menus.map((menu) => <Menu.Item>{label} {menu.menus?.map((menu) => <Menu.Item />))</Menu.Item>)) and so on
```

But if you do not want to edit your logic too much, add unique key to each menu and add prefix like {index1}-{index2}-{index3} so you could find active element by prefix and index

If starts with 1, then menu level 1 index 1 is active

If starts with 1-1, then menu level 2 index 1 is active and so on